# Flash not firing when in live view

Tags: flash, canon-60d, yongnuo

I have a Canon 60D and a Yongnuo YN560-III flash, everything works fine normally, but when i go in live view mode the flash doesn't fire
Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go into the Live View Settings menu (red tab no.4) and turn **Silent Shooting** off.  Then the flash will fire.  For some reason silent shooting is not compatible with 3rd party speedlites.

Comment: The reason is because the camera doesn't detect non E-TTL flashes mounted on the hot shoe.